# I had no idea this line of code would work. Is there anything I should know about implementations like this?

Tags: php, function, inline

I had no idea something like this (javascript-esque inline function) would work in PHP. As someone who spends a lot of time writing javascript/jquery, I was pretty stunned when my 'i wonder if this will work'-attempt actually worked.

```
usort($inbox_messages, function($a, $b){
    return strtotime($b["date"]) - strtotime($a["date"]);
});
```

Now, is there anything I should know about implementations like that? Performance issues, backwards compatibility, scope etc.

Is this common practice, or bad code?

Comment: What are you talking about? What should / shouldn't work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This feature is called [anonymous functions](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php), and it becomes available since PHP 5.3:

> Anonymous functions, also known as closures, allow the creation of
>   functions which have no specified name. They are most useful as the
>   value of callback parameters, but they have many other uses.

There's a (slight) difference in scope resolution as well for them:

> Closures may also inherit variables from the parent scope. Any such
>   variables must be declared in the function header. **Inheriting
>   variables from the parent scope is not the same as using global
>   variables.**

So, in this example:

```
$total = 0.00;
$callback = function ($quantity, $product) use ($tax, &$total)
{
    $pricePerItem = constant(__CLASS__ . "::PRICE_" . strtoupper($product));
    $total += ($pricePerItem * $quantity) * ($tax + 1.0);
};
array_walk($this->products, $callback);
```

... from that documentation page both `$tax` and `$total` are effectively injected into a `closure` ($callback) scope without using `global` keyword.

Anonymous functions are in fact objects of [Closure](http://php.net/manual/en/class.closure.php) class. And it's not just an implementation feature: as (since PHP 5.4) these functions can use `$this` object (similar to a context object in JavaScript), there are some useful methods that can change this context ([Closure::bind](http://php.net/manual/en/closure.bind.php), [Closure::bindTo](http://php.net/manual/en/closure.bindto.php) - compare these with [Function.bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind), for example).

Speaking more specifically, it's actually a good practice using anonymous functions when `map`/`filter`-ing collection, as these functions won't go into the global scope. But, of course, it's not a solution if you need your code to work on PHP 5.2.

Answer (score 2):

Backward compatability can be a problem if you need to distribute your code to run in diverse environments. [Anonymous functions](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php) are *not* supported prior to PHP 5.3.  Older hosting platforms and enterprise server installations are often still stuck on 5.2.x with vendor-supported Linux distributions, etc.

This has been changing rapidly over the past year, but will remain an issue to consider for a couple of years yet as the support cycles on those older installations expire.

For issues relating to variable scope and the `use` keyword, have a look at [the linked documentation on anonymous functions](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php).